# How to Autowired properties file to Environment variable?

Tags: maven, spring-4

My maven project fail to autowired my properties file into Environment variable. I am using spring 4.2.3.

This is the error when I run maven:test

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@57e1b0c: startup date [Sun Dec 20 08:55:34 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 20, 2015 8:55:34 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/home/bryan-1/workspace/2015dec_riot/test/target/test-classes/applicationContext.xml]
Dec 20, 2015 8:55:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [application.it.properties]
Dec 20, 2015 8:55:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JMSProperties' defined in file [/home/bryan-1/workspace/2015dec_riot/test/target/classes/test/JMSProperties.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [test.JMSProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b873400b]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.it.properties" />

    <!-- bean definitions here -->
</beans>
```

This is my properties class:

```
@Configuration
public class JMSProperties {

    ....

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public JMSProperties() {

        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

This is the Test case generated by Maven by default:

```
public class AppTest
    extends TestCase
{

    @Autowired
    JMSProperties properties;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppTest.class);

    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/applicationContext.xml");

    /**
     * Create the test case
     *
     * @param testName name of the test case
     */
    public AppTest( String testName )
    {
        super( testName );
    }

    /**
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     */
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    public void testApp()
    {
        logger.info(properties.getMatchMakerPassword());
    }
}
```

My Dependences:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logging framework dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: This tutorial helped alot - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception is a NPE in the constructor of JMSProperties, it would help to know what is your code there. Your post if not very helpful:

```
 public JMSProperties() {
        ....
    }
```

My guess is that you try to use env in there. At this point env in null, because spring has to instantiate the class first, and then inject the fields. Hence the NPE.

Comment: Thats not that case. I removed all contents from the constructor. and had a String get() method to return value.